# With Domain Controller admin access, how can I see which systems users are logged into?

Tags: domain-controller, sysadmin

I have a nifty list of users here in my "pumpkin" group. I was hoping it would be easy for me to check who is logged in for several reasons:

1. I don't want to interrupt a user with a prompt... If theyre disconnected, great I'll RDP in.
2. For helping users with troubleshooting, I can determine on their behalf, where they are logged in.

Its also just a great ability to have. Better yet, is there a CMD way to do it on my current system, without even logging into the DC?

Comment: -1 with no comment. Care to chime in with some reasoning Mr Secret McJudgerson?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as a single place in AD that will answer "who is logged in where". You'll need to query every machine to find who's logged in with an interactive session. You certainly don't need to be logged into the DC to do that, you just need to run it from a machine that can reach every target, and with an account that is allowed to make the query.

Domain Admin isn't required, you just need local administrator on every target (and it's possible a lower level of access could do it as well.)

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to give me this information! With this I can now go find the rest of the information!